# Javascript: trim off stars or space at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string which can end either with `" *"` or `" **"` or just without space and star.
I have to trim of any space or stars at the end of the string, but I can't get it to work

```
trimStarsOff(strWithStars: string): string {
    const returnStr = strWithStars;
    if (strWithStars.includes('*')) {
      const test = strWithStars.replace(' \\*$', '');
      cy.log(`test ${test}`);
    }
    return returnStr;
}
```

The stars remain in my case:

```
test "Some words test *"

test "Other words test2 *"
```

What do I miss?

Comment: also tried: /[ \\*]*$/

Comment: A regexp has to be inside slashes. When the first argument to `replace()` is a string, it's an exact match, not a regexp.

Comment: try this : const test =strWithStars.replace(/[*]/g, '');

Comment: If you have more information to add, edit the question, don't write it in a comment.

Comment: …also your function returns `returnStr`, not the updated `test`

Answer (score 2):

Please use multiple replace with g flag.

```
function trimStarsOff(strWithStars) {
    var returnStr = strWithStars.replace(/\*/g, '');
    return returnStr.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use a regular expression literal instead of a string. Also, use `+` to allow one or more asterisks to be replaced.

```js
const trimStarsOff = s => s.replace(/ \*+$/, '');
console.log(trimStarsOff('Some words test *'));
console.log(trimStarsOff('Test ***'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a regex in a string instead of just using the /regex/ format (technically you could also use the RegExp constructor with a string). You also don't need to check if you need to replace, just attempt a replacement and if you get the input echoed as the output, that's fine.

```js
function trimStarsOff(strWithStars) {
    return strWithStars.replace(/ \*+$/, '');
}

console.log(trimStarsOff("foo bar"));
console.log(trimStarsOff("banana sandwich *"));
console.log(trimStarsOff("corn on the cob **"));
console.log(trimStarsOff("stack overflow"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it universal with any number of spaces and stars:

```js
const log = str => console.log(JSON.stringify(str));

function trimStarsOff(strWithStars) {
    return strWithStars.replace(/[*\s]+$/, '');
}

log(trimStarsOff("foo bar"));
log(trimStarsOff("banana sandwich *"));
log(trimStarsOff("corn on the cob * *"));
log(trimStarsOff("stack overflow  *** *"));
```